# Parallel processing in c# with EF call

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

In Parallel foreach loop I'm calling external service to do some object specific checks. EF doesn't seem to like it at all, and throws InvalidOperationException saying: "The context cannot be used while the model is being created."

Is there any way I can resolve this issue in the parallel loop, or is this basically me calling the non-thread-safe environment what will never work?

My code looks like so:

```
Parallel.ForEach(users, user =>
{
    try
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref countAll);
        Console.WriteLine("Task Id {0} processing user: {1}", Task.CurrentId, user.Id);

        foreach (var item in user.somePropertyList)
        {
            var someCheck =  _internalService.Method(item.SomeProperty);
```

_internal service uses EF to make a check

Comment: What is your code? Can you show us a minimal example how you create/dispose your context and run the parallel tasks?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that your parallel `foreach` tries to create multiple `DataContext`s concurrently for the first time. This is not allowed with EF.

When an EF context is created for the first time, it will also be implicitely initialized, i.e. "the model is being created". If concurrent code wants to create another context it has to wait until the first context has been successfully initialized.

You could solve this by extracting the first parallelized task. Run this one without any parallel tasks and start parallel processing after the first task has finished.

```
if (!users.Any())
    return;

Process(users.First())

Parallel.ForEach(users.Skip(1), user =>
{
    Process(user)
}
```

Alternatively you could run a cheap dummy operation at start-up whose main purpose is to initialize the context. After that everything can be done in parallel.

```
_internalService.DoWarmUp();

Parallel.ForEach(users, user =>
{
    Process(user)
}
```

Comment: It won't create just 2 `DataContext`, it'll create as many `DataContext` as thread could be created for processing the data. It depends on how many cores the computer has.

Comment: @Abbondanza, thanks for your input. I'm using dependency injection, so my approach was to create new instance of service per user, what gives me new context each time. I use it for read-only so don't use UoW aspect of EF. It works fine now, but I'm wondering if my approach is not going to be fairly expensive?